# Continuity and Inverse Preservation of Boundedness Implies Preservation of Closed Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, bounded-variation, field-theory

Sorry about the rather long title - wasn't sure what else to call it!

Here is my question:

> Let $f : \Bbb R^n \rightarrow \Bbb R^m$ be continuous and such that $f^{-1}(F)$ is bounded whenever $F$ is bounded. Is it then true that $f(E)$ is closed whenever $E$ is closed? [We are not assuming *uniform* continuity.]

(This is a kind of reverse direction of the standard "continuous if and only if inverse image preserves closedness/openness.)

If it is not true, then please don't just give an example with no motivation! :)

Thank you in advance! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. If $y_n$ is a sequence in $f(E)$ for some closed set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ which converges to $y$, then the set $M:=\{y_n\}$ is bounded. Hence $f^{-1}(M)$ is bounded and therefore there exists a bounded(!) sequence $x_n$ in this set with $f(x_n)=y_n$. Since $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, we find a converging subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ converging to some $x$ (because we are in finite dimension). Because $E$ is close we have $x\in E$. Now, $f$ is continuous, thus $f(x_{n_k})$ converges to $f(x)$, but at the same time it converges to $y$. Consequently, $y=f(x)\in f(E)$.

Comment: +1 our answers are almost identical but you answered quicker by 50 seconds :)

Comment: Thank you very much. :) To be honest, not actually that bad - I should really have got it; not having a great day mathswise! =P

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of elements of $f(E)$ converging to $x\in \overline{f(E)}$ - we wish to show that $x\in f(E)$.

Choose a sequence $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of elements of $E$ such that $f(y_n)=x_n$. We know that $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and therefore has a convergent subsequence $\{y_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$. Since $E$ is closed, the limit $y$ of this convergent sequence is an element of $E$.

Since $f$ is continuous,

$f(y)$

$=f(\lim_{k\to\infty} y_{n_k})$

$=\lim_{k\to\infty} f(y_{n_k})$

$=\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k}$

$=x$.

Therefore, $x\in f(E)$, and the proof is complete.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think that you have explicitly used the bit about boundedness - I believe that it was used when you said  We know that $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$".

Comment: Other than that, thank you very much. :) To be honest, not actually that bad - I should really have got it; not having a great day mathswise! =P

Comment: Hi @SmileySam, right, we use the assumption when we assert that $\{y_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The proof was (more or less) "definition pushing" :)

Comment: Thank you for giving me the head start of 50 sec :o) Cheers!

Comment: I always find these awkward though - going to push the definitions in the right way and order! I also tend to start the solution incorrectly by, in this example for instance, assuming continuity and the inverse image bit, then trying to prove the result using closedness part way through. Definitely better to assume continuity and closedness then use inverse image bit!

Comment: By the wording, I mean when they give you some conditions, then say "show that something happens whenever something else". Would be much easier if they just put the "something else" in the original conditions, then ask to show the "something"! (At least, would be for me - need to remember this!)

Comment: Hi @SmileySam, you will get better at it with practice :) The key with these sorts of results is to know many different characterizations of the same property (e.g., continuity, closededness) and to be able to (mentally) pass quickly from one to the other as if they are the same (although these characterizations are logically equivalent, to a beginner they seem different enough that the beginner may not be aware which characterization is appropriate for which context).

Comment: Thank you :). I've got a month before the exam, so should be able to get used to it. It's a second analysis course, and I had the same issues with the first one at the time last year, but then it was my best course - hopefully the same this year! =D